# How to check when a user Last visited SharePoint Site using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-server, csom

Is there a way to find out when a user last logged into SharePoint using CSOM?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to find out when a user last visited?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92380/how-to-find-out-when-a-user-last-visited)

Comment: It does not answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

powershell

http://admin-sharepoint.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/get-users-last-logon-time-and-date.html

C#

```
public DateTime Get(string attr, string UserName)
    {

        DomainConfiguration domainConfig = new DomainConfiguration();
        using (new SPMonitoredScope("AD Properties"))
        {
            using (DirectoryEntry domain = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domainConfig.DomainName, domainConfig.UserName, domainConfig.Password))
            {
                //DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(domain, "(|(objectClass=organizationalUnit)(objectClass=container)(objectClass=builtinDomain)(objectClass=domainDNS))");
                DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(domain);
                searcher.PageSize = 1000;
                searcher.Filter = "(SAMAccountName='" + UserName + "')";
                //searcher.Filter = "(|(objectCategory=group)(objectCategory=person))";
                searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user) (cn=" + UserName + "))";
                var user = searcher.FindOne();
                DateTime LastLogon = DateTime.FromFileTime((Int64)user.Properties["lastLogon"].Value);
                return LastLogon;
            }
        }
    }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796547/how-to-get-last-login-details-time-for-all-users